# JPA Entity not stored OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa

i trie to run the following code.
But the child is not created to the parent Entity 'Erfasser'.
If i comment out the line erfasser.getErfasst().add(neu) everything works fine.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    Erfasser erfasser = new Erfasser();
    erfasser.setEmail("benjamin.koubik@auditweb.de");
    erfasser.setPasswort("counting88");
    gesamtAnzahl.einfuegenErfasser(erfasser);

    Erfasst neu = new Erfasst();
    neu.setDatum(new Date());
    neu.setJuristische(1);
    neu.setNatuerliche(0);

    gesamtAnzahl.einfuegen(neu);

    erfasser.getErfasst().add(neu);

    gesamtAnzahl.update(erfasser);

}
```

[image]

Only the Erfasser itself is stored correctly in the DB.

```
@Entity
public class Erfasser implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Erfasser() {
    super();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int erfasser_id;

@Column(length = 50)
@Email(message = "Inkorrekt EMail")
private String email;

@Column(length = 30)
private String passwort;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "erfasser_id", name = "erfasst_id_referenz")
private List<Erfasst> erfasst;

public int getErfasser_id() {
    return erfasser_id;
}

public void setErfasser_id(int erfasser_id) {
    this.erfasser_id = erfasser_id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPasswort() {
    return passwort;
}

public void setPasswort(String passwort) {
    this.passwort = passwort;
}

public List<Erfasst> getErfasst() {
    return erfasst;
}

public void setErfasst(List<Erfasst> erfasst) {
    this.erfasst = erfasst;
 }

}
```

And here my SessionBeans:

AnzahlErfasstGesamtLocal.java

```
@Local
public interface AnzahlErfasstGesamtLocal {

public abstract List<Integer> gesamt();

public abstract List<Erfasst> gesamtNatuerlich();

public abstract List<Erfasst> gesamtJuristisch();

public abstract void einfuegenErfasser(Erfasser e);

public abstract void einfuegen(Erfasst e);

public abstract void update(Erfasser e);

public abstract void loeschen(Erfasst e);
}
```

AnzahlErfasstGesamt.java

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AnzahlErfasstGesamt implements AnzahlErfasstGesamtLocal {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public AnzahlErfasstGesamt() {
}

@Override
public List<Integer> gesamt() {

    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Erfasst> gesamtNatuerlich() {
    try {
        TypedQuery<Erfasst> q = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Erfasst e WHERE e.natuerliche = 1 AND e.juristische = 0; ", Erfasst.class);
        List<Erfasst> liste = q.getResultList();
        if (!liste.isEmpty()) {
            return liste;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public List<Erfasst> gesamtJuristisch() {
    try {
        TypedQuery<Erfasst> q = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Erfasst e WHERE e.juristische = 1 AND e.natuerliche = 0; ", Erfasst.class);
        List<Erfasst> liste = q.getResultList();
        if (!liste.isEmpty()) {
            return liste;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void einfuegen(Erfasst e) {
    em.persist(e);

}

@Override
public void update(Erfasser e) {
    em.merge(e);

}

@Override
public void loeschen(Erfasst e) {
    em.remove(em.merge(e));

}

@Override
public void einfuegenErfasser(Erfasser e) {
    em.persist(e);

}

}
```

Comment: more info req. Edit question, add source code of entities update method

Comment: What is "gesamtAnzahl"? A service?

Comment: @jklee - have edit my code - No its my SessionBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with JPA - something is wrong in external code (and certainly with your description of the problem). For example I don't see where the actual `erfasst` list is created - if nothing happens in `einfuegenErfasser` (whatever that means), then you will get a NullPointerException while trying to add an element to a null list. Is that what happens?

Comment: That's right - exactly einfuegenErfasser is a method in my sessionBean

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the combination of JPA entity setup and the code using it. The JPA entity `Erfasser` has `CascadeType.ALL`, therefore the `gesamtAnzahl.update(erfasser);` updates the child entities `erfasst` with it. At the same time you do not setup the `erfasser` reference on the `neu` instance. You need to do something alog the line `neu.setErfasser(erfasser)` before `gesamtAnzahl.update(erfasser);`.

On separated line of concern, using the native German naming drives my head crazy, even though I am more German then English speaker.